# Ruby Variable holds HTML elements

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So I lets say I have a variable that holds some HTML elements. How do I get that to display correctly?

Example

```
@mainArticle = "<p>Hey this is an example</p>"

//HTML Page

<div class="mainArticleSpace">
     <%= @mainArticle %>
</div>
```

I've tried this and it includes the p tags when you try to display.

Comment: `<%= @mainArticle.html_safe %>`

Comment: Thank you Sergio! Just didnt know what to search for I guess. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only show allowed html tags and attributes**

You can sanitize the content to make sure only safe tags and attributes are accepted.

```
<%= sanitize @mainArticle %>
```

And if you want to specify the tags yourself you can do it as well.

```
<%= sanitize(@mainArticle, tags: %w(p h1), attributes: %w(id class)) %>
```

Check out the rails [sanitize helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) documentation for more options and how to configure it.

**Remove all html tags**

You can also use strip_tags if you really want to get rid of all html tags.

```
<%= strip_tags @mainArticle %>
```

Check out the [strip_tags documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags)